# Override em atribuições Java

Tags: java

Para que serve o override em atribuições no java?? Exemplo : estou atribuindo valores em uma determinada classe do pacote que eu criei no netbeans . Mas tem em um slide que depois de todas as atribuições feitas ao objeto da classe , tem um @Override toString sendo que eu tenho mais de um tipo de variável , então queria saber para que serve e apesar de eu estar começando java vendo estrutura de dados , estou vendo lista encadeada .

Comment: `@Override` é uma anotação, assim como tudo que começa com `@` em Java. E anotações tem _casas_ específicas; no caso do `@Override`, sua casa é sempre um método, não pode ser um atributo nem um construtor, nem um parâmetro